# what does "reduce A problem to B problem in polynomial time" mean?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, reductions

It is kind of NP-complete problem.
For example,

- **A problem**:
  Given a sequence of numbers, return the maximum value within these numbers.
- **B problem**:
  Given a sequence of numbers, return start index and end index of the maximum sum segment within these numbers.

To show how to reduce A problem to B problem in O(n) time.
Does this means we could solve A problem by solving B problems?
It seems a little bit strange for this case.

Comment: This is a standard definition in complexity and computability theory, which can be found in any textbook or set of lecture notes, and on hundreds of websites. There doesn't seem to be any benefit in somebody writing out the definition yet again. I suggest you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_%28complexity%29) and ask questions about any specific parts you don't understand.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Actually, since the problems here are not decision problems, it is not immediately clear what kind of reduction to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of reductions, the most common of which are *many-one reductions* and *oracle reductions*.

A **many-one reduction** from $A$ to $B$ is a computable function $f$ mapping strings to strings such that $x \in A$ iff $f(x) \in B$.

An **oracle reduction** from $A$ to $B$ is a computable function $f$ which has access to a $B$-oracle, and satisfies $f(x) = 1$ iff $x \in A$. That is, $f$ decides membership in $A$. The machine has a mechanism for accessing the oracle. When the oracle is presented a string $y$, it tells the program whether $y \in B$ or not.

Every many-one reduction $f$ can be formulated as an oracle reduction: the oracle reduction first computes $f(x)$, then asks the oracle whether $f(x) \in B$, and outputs the oracle's answer.

In the theory of NP-completeness, we always use many-one reductions. Reducing a problem A to a problem B in time $T(n)$ means giving a many-one reduction from A to B which runs in time $T(n)$. In particular, reducing A to B in polynomial time means reducing A to B in time $O(n^k)$ for some fixed $k$.

In your particular case it is hard to tell which kind of reduction is meant, since your problems are not decision problems. Perhaps some restricted kind of linear time oracle reduction, say one accessing the oracle only once. It's also not clear what computation model you should use. Under some computation models you can solve problem A in linear time, and so such a reduction trivially exists (it never asks the oracle anything).